# How would one go about building true React SPA theme in Shopify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify, liquid, shopify-app

How would one go about building React SPA theme, which will handle routing client-side and will use all the benefits of Shopify Plus plan, (e.g. managed hosting, bandwidth, etc...).

All examples I could find are using Shopify Storefront API as a headless seems, but we all looking for a more “hybrid” solution relying on Shopify Plus servers, but at the same time using as less liquid as possible.